# Patent search firms #2

Tags: search

To committ a search to a search firm is it necessary to sign a confidentiality agreement?

The results for non-english language patents are confined just to abstracts and title  or search firms usually also translate foreign patents and search into them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want a confidentiality agreement to protect your rights. Most patent search engines now include an automatic machine translation from a variety of languages and you should get that from the search firm. Sometimes you can't determine what you need without a human or assisted translation. You could contract for that separately.